# How to reference previous(ordered/filtered) results in dynamic LINQ expression (System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, dynamic-linq

I need to dynamically generate this query.

```
var rows = this.Context.Offers.Select(t => new
{
    t.Id,
    t.PartnerId,
    address = t.Partner.Addresses
        .OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.IsDefault)
        .Select(t2 => new { t2.Address.Address, t2.Address.Postcode.ZipCode })
        .FirstOrDefault()
}).ToArray();
```

I am using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) and tried this:

```
var s = "new(Id,PartnerId, Partner.Addresses.OrderByDescending(IsDefault).FirstOrDefault().Select(new(Address.Address, Address.Postcode.ZipCode)) as address)";
var rows = this.Context.Offers.Select(s).ToDynamicArray();
```

but it returns error:

> System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: 'No property or
>   field 'Address' exists in type 'DbOffer''

This is probably logic and problem lies here `Select(new(Address.Address...`, but how can I reference what `Partner.Addresses.OrderByDescending(IsDefault).FirstOrDefault()` returns?

C# LINQ can reference previous(table) result as variable (`t` and `t2` in my specific case), but dynamic linq doesn't work like this.

I don't know why exactly (probably because I found `it` in [documentation](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#_Current_Instance)) I also tried with `Select(new(it.Address.Address,` but I get same error.

Comment: It should (and does) work. But `FirstOrDefault()` in the dynamic query must be after `Select` as in the static query. The exception is misleading.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much.